# How to find the total amount from given percentage

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle, average

I am trying to answer this question from internet for my mathematics practice.

```
What was the original price of an item if a discount of 20 percent

reduced the price to Rs.100? 

A. Rs.80 

B. Rs.120

C. Rs.125

D. Rs.150

E. Rs.250
```

How we can find its answer? What formula we can use and how we can solve it step by step, though it looks an easy question to me but I am out of touch for approximately 3 years

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is the original price, $\displaystyle\frac{100-20}{100}x$ would reflect the price after a discount of 20 percent.

Answer (score 1):

$$x-20\%x=100$$
$$x-\frac{20}{100}x=100$$
$$x-x/5=100$$
$$4x/5=100$$
$$x=500/4$$
$$x=125$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the original price is Rs. 100 . 
Then the discount on the item be Rs. 20.
And discounted price would be Rs.80.

So we can use unitary method , and find out. 
When the discounted price is 80 then original is 100.
So if the discounted price be 100 , then original would be ?

$\dfrac{100 *100}{80}$

Answer (score 0):

$$x-20\%\cdot x=x-0.2x=\mathrm{rs}100$$
$$\mathrm{rs}100=80\%\cdot x$$ where $x$ is the total amount

So $x=\frac{\mathrm{rs}100}{80%}=\frac{\mathrm{rs}100}{0.8}=\boxed{\mathrm{rs}125}$

And to confirm:
$\mathrm{rs}125-20\%\cdot\mathrm{rs}125=\mathrm{rs}125-0.2\cdot\mathrm{rs}125=\mathrm{rs}100$

Try and test it out.